# Find primitive semiperfect numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

### Semiperfect numbers

A semiperfect/pseudoperfect number is an integer equal to the sum of a part of or all of its divisors (excluding itself). Numbers which are equal to the sum of all of their divisors are perfect.

```
Divisors of 6 : 1,2,3
      6 = 1+2+3 -> semiperfect (perfect)
Divisors of 28 : 1,2,4,7,14
      28 = 14+7+4+2+1 -> semiperfect (perfect)
Divisors of 40 : 1,2,4,5,8,10,20
      40 = 1+4+5+10+20 or 2+8+10+20 -> semiperfect
```

### Primitive

A primitive semiperfect number is a semiperfect number with no semiperfect divisors (except itself :))

```
Divisors of 6 : 1,2,3
      6  = 1+2+3 -> primitive
Divisors of 12 : 1,2,3,4,6
      12 = 2+4+6 -> semiperfect
```

As references, please use the OEIS series [A006036](https://oeis.org/A006036) for primitive semiperfect numbers, and [A005835](https://oeis.org/A005835) for semiperfects.

### Goal

Write a program or a function in any language.
It will take as input a number n as a function parameter or from STDIN/your language's closest alternative, and will output all the primitive semi-perfect numbers from 1 to n (inclusive).

The output must be formated as `6[separator]20[separator]28[separator]88...` where [separator] is either as newline, a space or a comma. There must not be a starting [separator] nor a ending one.

**Edit : you can leave a trailing newline**

### Examples

input :

```
5
```

output :

input :

```
20
```

output :

```
6
20
```

input :

```
100
```

output :

```
6 20 28 88
```

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so the shortest code in bytes win.

Don't try to fool us with [loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) please :).

I'd be glad you could leave an explanation of your golfed code once you think you're done golfing it!

### As this challenge already have some nice answers, and is slowly getting quiet, I'll put an end to it. The winner of this code-golf will be decided on Monday 29th, 00:00 GMT. Well done to all of you that have answered, and good luck to those who will try to beat them :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
VQI}KhNsMyJf!%KTSNI!@JYeaYK
```

*1 byte thanks to @Jakube*

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQI%7DKhNsMyJf!%25KTSNI!%40JYeaYK&input=100&debug=0)

```
VQI}KhNsMyJf!%KTSNI!@JYeaYK
                                Implicit:
                                Y = []
                                Q = eval(input())
VQ                              for N in range(Q):
    KhN                         K = N+1
           f    SN              filter T over range(1, N)
            !%KT                the logical not of K%T.
                                This is the list of divisors of K.
          J                     Store the list in J.
         y                      Create all of its subsets.
       sM                       Map each subset to its sum.
  I}K                           If K is in that list: (If K is semiperfect)
                  I!@JY         If the intersection of J (the divisors)
                                and Y (the list of primitive semiperfect numbers)
                                is empty:
                        aYK     Append K to Y
                       e        And print its last element, K.
```

Comment: @AlexA. Thanks! It is necessary to append `K` to `Y` to build `Y`, which is needed elsewhere. However, I could do the printing separately, such as with `aYKK` instead of `eaYK`. It's 4 bytes either way, however.

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, <s>161</s> 149 bytes

```matlab
n->(S(m)=!isempty(filter(i->i==unique(i)&&length(i)>1&&all(j->m%j<1,i),partitions(m)));for i=2:n S(i)&&!any(S,filter(k->i%k<1,1:i-1))&&println(i)end)
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts an integer as input and prints the numbers to STDOUT separated by a newline. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=n->...`.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```matlab
# Define a function that determines whether the input is semiperfect
# (In the submission, this is defined as a named inline function within the
# primary function. I've separated it here for clarity.)

function S(m)
    # Get all integer arrays which sum to m
    p = partitions(m)

    # Filter the partitions to subsets of the divisors of m
    d = filter(i -> i == unique(i) && length(i) > 1 && all(j -> m % j == 0, i), p)

    # If d is nonempty, the input is semiperfect
    !isempty(d)
end

# The main function

function f(n)
    # Loop through all integers from 2 to n
    for i = 2:n
        # Determine whether i is semiperfect
        if S(i)
            # If no divisors of i are semiperfect, print i
            !any(S, filter(k -> i % k == 0, 1:i-1) && println(i)
        end
    end
end
```

Examples:

```matlab
julia> f(5)

julia> f(40)
6
20
28
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (*ES6*) 172

Run the snippet below to test

```js
f=
v=>eval("for(n=h=[];n++<v;!t*i&&n>1?h[n]=1:0){for(r=[l=i=t=1];++i<n;)n%i||(h[i]?t=0:l=r.push(i));for(i=0;t&&++i<1<<l;)r.map(v=>i&(m+=m)?t-=v:0,t=n,m=.5)}''+Object.keys(h)")


// Less golfed

ff=v=>
{
   h=[]; // hashtable with numbers found so far

   for (n=1; n <= v; n++)
   {
      r=[1],l=1; // r is the list of divisors, l is the length of this list
      t=1; // used as a flag, will become 0 if a divisor is in h
      for(i=2; i<n; i++)
      {
         if (n%i == 0)
            if (h[i])
               t = 0; // found a divisor in h, n is not primitive
            else
               l = r.push(i); // add divisor to r and adjust l
      }
      if (t != 0) // this 'if' is merged with the for below in golfed code
      { 
         // try all the sums, use a bit mask to find combinations
         for(i = 1; t != 0 && i < 1<<l; i++)
         {
            t = n; // start with n and subtract, if ok result will be 0 
            m = 0.5; // start with mask 1/2 (nice that in Javascript we can mix int and floats)
            r.forEach( v=> i & (m+=m) ? t -= v : 0);
         }
         if (t == 0 && n > 1) h[n] = 1; // add n to the hashmap (the value can be anything)
      }
   }
   // the hashmap keys list is the result
   return '' + Object.keys(h) // convert to string, adding commas
}

(test=()=> O.textContent=f(+I.value))();
```

```html
<input id=I type=number oninput="test()" value=999><pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 54 bytes

This solution feels a bit awkward, but since there have been few answers, and none in CJam, I thought I'd post it anyway:

```
Lli),2>{_N,1>{N\%!},_@&!\_,2,m*\f{.*:+}N#)e&{N+}&}fNS*
```

A good part of the increment over the posted Pyth solution comes from the fact that, as far as I could find, CJam does not have an operator to enumerate all subsets of a set. So it took some work to complete that with available operators. Of course, if there actually is a simple operator I missed, I'll look kind of silly. :)

Explanation:

```
L     Start stack with empty list that will become list of solutions.
li    Get input N and convert to int.
),2>  Build list of candidate solutions [2 .. N].
{     Start for loop over all candidate solutions.
_     Copy list of previous solutions, needed later to check for candidate being primitive.
N,1>  Build list of possible divisors [1 .. N-1].
{N\%!},  Filter list to only contain actual divisors of N.
_     Check if one of divisors is a previous solution. Start by copying divisor list.
@     Pull copy of list with previous solutions to top of stack
&!    Intersect the two lists, and check the result for empty. Will be used later.
\     Swap top two elements, getting divisor list back to top.
_,    Get length of divisor list.
2,    Put [0 1] on top of stack.
m*    Cartesian power. Creates all 0/1 sequences with same length as divisor list.
\     Swap with divisor list.
f{.*:+}  Calculate element by element product of all 0/1 sequences with divisors,
         and sum up the values (i.e. dot products of 0/1 sequences with divisors).
         The result is an array with all possible divisor sums.
N#)  Find N in list of divisor sums, and covert to truth value.
e&   Logical and with earlier result from primitive test.
{N+}&  Add N to list of solutions if result is true.
}fN  Phew! We finally made it to the end of the for loop, and have a list of solutions.
S*   Join the list of solutions with spaces in between.
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Lli)%2C2%3E%7B_N%2C1%3E%7BN%5C%25!%7D%2C_%40%26!%5C_%2C2%2Cm*%5Cf%7B.*%3A%2B%7DN%23)e%26%7BN%2B%7D%26%7DfNS*&input=100)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 263 Bytes

```php
function m($a,$n){for($t=1,$b=2**count($a);--$b*$t;$t*=$r!=$n,$r=0)foreach($a as$k=>$v)$r+=($b>>$k&1)*$v;return$t;}for($o=[];$i++<$argn;m($d,$i)?:$o=array_merge($o,range($r[]=$i,3*$argn,$i)))for($d=[],$n=$i;--$n*!in_array($i,$o);)$i%$n?:$d[]=$n;echo join(",",$r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#HY/BTsMwEETv/Yo0WlDsuBIFKQdcpwfUAxe4cKuqyEncxFRdR4tTCSH49bDJbaWZeTO72w/9sHJEgSpyQ6Doscv@DtXb@8fry0HoFVjq0KRFUaR6Oo/YRB8wuWZgFaD4OQfKIJqtgto8StmEESNrQm82UEuIGqI0QGsDqIDMg@CAs03PnsR@wcWUcBNAucmgLku43G@FhJsmF0dCjv8uBcEcTxp8nu@WOZrrWwVe7J9ZskT2u7o66hw7FVmcDzqeDHj1JJfEbBZiYbXM4ukszhtRrj1WCyJjOwShBfg7QEa3MwK1a/qQfAaPWapSfkLoafoH)

Expanded

```
function m($a,$n){ 
  for($t=1,$b=2**count($a);--$b*$t;$t*=$r!=$n,$r=0) #loop through bitmasks
    foreach($a as$k=>$v)$r+=($b>>$k&1)*$v; # loop through divisor array
  return$t;} # returns false for semiperfect numbers 
for($o=[];$i++<$argn;
m($d,$i)?
  :$o=array_merge($o,range($r[]=$i,3*$argn,$i))) # Make the result array and the array of multiples of the result array 
  for($d=[],$n=$i;--$n*!in_array($i,$o);) # check if integer is not in multiples array
    $i%$n?:$d[]=$n; # make divisor array
echo join(",",$r); #Output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
ÆDṖŒPS€i
ÆDÇ€TL’
RÇÐḟY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3@4zeXhzmlHJwUEP2pak8kF5B5uB7JCfB41zOQKOtx@eMLDHfMj////b2hgAAA)

**Explanation**

```
ÆDṖŒPS€i - helper function to check if input is a semiperfect number
ÆD       - list of divisors of input
  Ṗ      - except for the last one (the input)
   ŒP    - power set = every possible subset of divisors
     S€  - sum of each subset
       i - return truthy iff input is one of these

ÆDÇ€TL’ - helper function to check if input is a primitive semiperfect number
ÆD       - list of divisors of input
  Ç€     - replace each with if they are a semiperfect number, based on 
           the above helper function. If input is a primitive semiperfect 
           number, we get something like [0,0,0,0,0,94]. 
    T    - get all truthy values.
     L’  - return falsy iff there is only one truthy value

RÇÐḟY    - main link
R        - Range[input]
 ÇÐḟ     - Filter out those elements which are not primitive semiperfect
           numbers, based on the helper function
    Y    - join by newlines.
```